# How do I make my python code so that only text can be entered?

Tags: text, error-handling

import random

def diceRoll(number):
    roll = random.randint(1,number)
    print("Rolling a ",number," sided die.")
    return roll

def newAccount(playername):
    print("Greetings ", playername,"! We'll generate your charecter's attributes by rolling some die")
    skillroll = 10 + (int(round((diceRoll(12)/diceRoll(4)))))
    strengthroll = 10 + (int(round((diceRoll(12)/diceRoll(4)))))
    print("You have ",skillroll," skillpoints and ",strengthroll," strength!")
    class newplayer:
        name = playername
        skill = skillroll
        strength = strengthroll
    save(newplayer)

def save(newplayer):
    """Saves all details"""
    file = open("accounts.txt","a")
    file.write("CharacterName = '" + newplayer.name + "'\n")
    file.write("Strength = " + str(newplayer.strength) + '\n')
    file.write("Skill = " + str(newplayer.skill) + '\n')
    file.write("\n")
    print("Saved account")

**def newPlayer():
    try:
        player1 = input("What is your 1st player's name? ")
        newAccount(player1)
    except:
        print("Please only enter letters for your character name ")
        newPlayer()
newPlayer()**

print("      ")

player2 = input("What is your 2nd player's name? ")
newAccount(player2)

The part in bold is the part of the code I have attempted to alter to add some sort of error handling. Someone help me out here please, I know it's probably simple but I can't find an answer to this question anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Pythons RegEx would be a quite easy solution:

```
import re

if not re.match("[a-z]+$",inputString):
    #your exception handling
```